# Run two functions at once

Tags: arduino

This program is a simple program designed to plot at the same time both your & Uc on the serial monitor. Arduino runs through the first for loop & plot the F1 function and after that does the same with F2. My objective is to plot them both at the same time.

My idea is to actually take a small fraction of time, let's say 10 ms, to plot F1 & the next 10 ms to plot F2, but I don't know how to write this down. I think the millis function is the solution, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it.

```cpp
const short int R = 5000;
const float C = 0.0005;
const float TE = 0.1;
const float Tau = R*C;
const short int E = 5;
float t, Tinit,Tfin;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  //F1
  for ( t = 0; t <= 20; t = t+TE)
  {
      float Ur = E*exp(-t/Tau);
      Serial.println (Ur);
  }

  //F2
  for ( t = 0; t <= 20; t = t+TE)
  {
      float Uc = E*(1-exp(-t/Tau));
      Serial.println (Uc);
  }
}
```

Comment: So... why not just intersperse your lines together into a single loop?

Comment: In the future, keep in mind this site: https://arduino.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

[Thread](https://github.com/ivanseidel/ArduinoThread) can be used to solve your problem . It has a huge documentation , it is widely used library for Arduino(***unofficial***).
Give it a try.

It will be easy for you, if you see these :

1. [Example - 1](https://github.com/ivanseidel/ArduinoThread/blob/master/examples/SensorThread/SensorThread.ino) (thread instance example)
2. [Example - 2](https://github.com/ivanseidel/ArduinoThread/blob/master/examples/SimpleThread/SimpleThread.ino) (callback example)
3. [Example - 3](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/Arduino-Seven-Segment/blob/develop/SevenSegment.cpp) (It is still buggy , but I think it will help)

If you want to do it without libraries , then you need to create two functions , without those loops . Like

```
void f1()
{
  float Ur = E*exp(-t/Tau);
  Serial.println (Ur);
}

void f2()
{
  float Uc = E*(1-exp(-t/Tau));
  Serial.println (Uc);
}
```

Now inside "void loop()" you can implement the basic logic of threading , which will be pretty rough , but fulfill your requirements. Like :

```
void loop() {
unsigned long now = millis();

static unsigned long last_finger_update;
if (now - last_finger_update >= FINGER_UPDATE_PERIOD) {
    last_finger_update = now;
    f1();
}


static unsigned long last_wrist_update;
if (now - last_wrist_update >= WRIST_UPDATE_PERIOD) {
    last_wrist_update = now;
    f2();
}
}
```

You have to declare two variables

```
const unsigned long FINGER_UPDATE_PERIOD = 1000;
const unsigned long WRIST_UPDATE_PERIOD  = 1000;
```

All time units are in milliseconds. [This strategy](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/51066/proto-threading-2-functions) is collected from internet.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I cannot use any additional libraries.

Comment: I have updated the answer , please see , I guess it will benefit you

Comment: How does this avoid common threading problems like resource starvation? It seems like an unnecessarily complicated solution.

Comment: It is unnecessarily complicated , but without libraries , I don't have another approach :sad:

Answer (score 1):

The most deterministic way of handling this is simply:

```
for (t = 0; t <= 20; t = t + TE) {
    float Ur = E*exp(-t/Tau);
    float Uc = E*(1-exp(-t/Tau));
    Serial.println (Ur);
    Serial.println (Uc);
}
```

More generally, you can implement a primitive resource scheduler:

```
while (true) {
    task_one();
    task_two();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that Easily if you run RTOS in MCU  as you know other solutions will also be sequential...

I've been using TridentTD_EasyFreeRTOS library it has easy way of having multiple tasks and controlling them in different sketch files..